# Convert string 'Tomorrow' to momentjs

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I know that this is a bit of an specific question, but I've been all over the place of the [momentjs docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/) and I have not been able to locate a way to do something like the following.

```
moment().fromString('tomorrow')
// 'The date of tomorrow'
moment().fromString('next week')
// 'The date of next week'
moment().fromString('yesterday')
// 'The date of yesterday'
```

I know this is a completelly invented method but, is there a way to get the date for `tomorrow`, or `next week` or `yesterday` without having to pass the parameters specifically.
Putting it together, is there a way to make a language lexical resume to a date?

**PS:** I know I can do `moment().add(1, 'day')` and it will give me the date of tomorrow, the issue is that I want to know if there is a dictionary already with `tomorrow`, `next week`, `in 2 days`? and so on that could be "human friendly" dates.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/2415

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I was just reading that, maybe I can create a feature request in moment linking this issue to see if there is a way to make a Dict that would convert "human friendly" dates to moment?

Comment: Yes, it's a feature I miss very often, I'd be happy to see it in momentjs (especially because it's mostly a job around translation files, at least for a basic usage)

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment-parseplus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fear that there is no built in method to map `tomorrow`, `next week` to moment values.

Anyway you can create your `fromString` adding it to [`moment.fn`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/)

> The `Moment` prototype is exposed through `moment.fn`. If you want to add your own functions, that is where you would put them.

Here an example:

```js
moment.fn.fromString = function(param){
  if( param === 'tomorrow' ){
    return this.clone().add(1, 'day');
  } else if( param === 'next week' ){
    return this.clone().add(1, 'week');
  } else if( param === 'yesterday' ){
    return this.clone().subtract(1, 'day');
  }
  
  return this;
}


console.log( moment().fromString('tomorrow').format() )
console.log( moment().fromString('next week').format() )
console.log( moment().fromString('yesterday').format() )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: For me this seems more like a lexical dictionary exposure problem. 
They have already a lot of the logic that is involved in the friendly date to string, but not the other way around, anyhow thank you for the answer :) `fromString` was just a fn example btw

Comment: Still something I wanted to avoid, but seems like it's going to be what I will have to do for now, in order to make the code work :(

Comment: @AlejandroVales yes, `fromString` is just a simple example of `moment.fn` (I posted it because you said in the comments that you wanted to _enrich the library_). I understand that a function with a list of `if` is not what you wanted, but I fear that there is no built-in dictionary that could help you (even in https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/2415 there is no suggested solution). I upvoted and added to favorites your question, to see if someone gives the solution you desire.

Comment: Thanks, **let's hope we are not alone**, and yeah, I also upvoted your answer cause for the current implementation is the only solution there is, so, well, it's so far so good :)

Comment: Instead of `param === 'tomorrow'` consider `/\btomorrow\b/i.test(param)`, or at least `param.toLowerCase() == 'tomorrow'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create conditions wherein if user chooses/types this string. Print the corresponding moment, so on and so forth.

```
if(str == 'tomorrow') 
{
moment().add(1, 'day')}
}
```

Comment: That is exactly something that I was trying to avoid, I don't want to make a dictionary for all of the cases in which a user could put the date of tomorrow, and I therefore wanted to use a library for that, and if not just enrich the library :)